# Microsoft Access Update Query

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to make a insurance company database.
I have a customer table where there is a field for their payment date, and also another field called PaymentTypeID which is linked to a PaymentType table. The ID is either 1 or 2 based on whether they pay monthly or annually.
I have another table which is for policies where there is an effective date, the date of when their policy is expiring, so it should either expire in a month or a year.

What I want is a query to update the effective date from the payment date in the policy table based on whether their paymenttypeID is 1 or 2.

I would rather this be done in Design view rather than sql view

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IIf` expression to set the value depending on the paymenttypeID. In the "Update To" row, use

```
= IIf(paymenttypeID = 1, valueToInsertIfPayedMonthly, valueToInsertIfPayedYearly)
```

Obviously, `valueToInsertIfPayedMonthly` and `...Yearly` need to be replaced by the actual values that you want to set.

If you have more than two values, use the [`Choose` function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Choose-Function-76230415-910f-463a-a799-cf7e90aa7fd4) instead of `IIf`.